Rigid plane curves
A curve is a continuous one-to-one image of the real line $\mathbb R$.
A space $X$ is rigid if the only homeomorphism of $X$ onto itself is the identity.
Is there a rigid curve in the plane?
I am specifically interested in curves which are self-entwined or limiting onto itself, which means that no open set intersects the curve in an arc. I also am willing to assume that  curves are smooth ($C^\infty$).

(You probably know this already, but ) if there is a rigid planar curve, it must have unbounded curvature. Any self-entwined curve with constant curvature is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb R$, and therefore not rigid. By the way, do you have a non-planar example of a rigid curve?

@WillBrian Yes, this is mentioned in "The geometry of laminations", Section 2.1, and I think that I see why it's true. In order for the curve to be rigid, it seems like each point would have to be a limit of points with curvatures tending to infinity.

Also, this might be related to an open problem about homogeneous curves, namely whether each is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ or is locally $\mathbb Q\times \mathbb R$. This problem is in two papers: "The orientation of matchbox manifolds" and "On one-to-one continuous images of R", both from 1991.
